# Getting time codes in video files easier

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows-10, video-processing

I am going through some videos to trim them (extracting parts of the video).

I know there is billions of software out there that can trim videos easily, but I haven't found any that does not recode the result.

My method right now is to open the video in MPC-BE -> play -> pause -> note down the time -> resume to find a place end the clip -> pause -> note down the end time for the clip. Then I take the time codes and use ffmpeg to extract the part. Usually with something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 01:50:00 -to 01:55:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

My question is is there an easier way to get the time codes? The best thing would be to use ffplay to playback and just hit a key-combo to copy the time code. But I am also open any other approach that will make it easier to get the timecodes. As you probably understand, writing down the time codes manually for 23 clips is a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## mpv

The player [mpv](https://mpv.io/) support scripts for custom functionality that is not part of the core player. There are several [user scripts](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/User-Scripts) available that involve cutting/trimming that may be helpful:

- [copyTime](https://github.com/Arieleg/mpv-copyTime) - Get the current time of the video and copy it to the clipboard with the format `HH:MM:SS.MS`.
- [trim.lua](https://github.com/aerobounce/trim.lua) - Create a trim of video files without transcoding. Utilizes `ffprobe` to fetch accurate keyframes.
- [splice](https://github.com/pvpscript/mpv-video-splice) - Create a video out of cuts made in the current playing video.
- [mpv_slicing_copying](https://github.com/snylonue/mpv_slicing_copy) - A fork from [mpv_slicing](https://github.com/Kagami/mpv_slicing). It will cut fragments of the video in original format instead of RGB.
- [excerpt](https://gitlab.com/lvml/mpv-plugin-excerpt) - Allows you to quickly create excerpts from media files, you just have to set begin and end markers.

## LosslessCut

[LosslessCut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut) is a GUI to `ffmpeg` for lossless trimming and cutting of video and audio files.

[image: losslesscut screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! mpv is probably what I am looking for, although I will have to try this out for a while and get used to it and report back here. LosslessCut had some serious performance issues with 4K HDR files.

Comment: [mpv_slicing](https://github.com/Kagami/mpv_slicing) did the trick for me. Although I had to modify it slightly for my need. [mpv-copyTime](https://github.com/Arieleg/mpv-copyTime) is also very helpful. Thanks a bunch for mentioning these.

Answer (score -2):

This is my method : With ffplay,

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':box=1:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh)" J1.mp4
```

where `J1`  is the file to play.

To write time in movie :

```
ffmpeg -start_at_zero -copyts -ss 00:00:14.435 -i showfreqs.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/Arial.ttf: fontsize=45:fontcolor=yellow:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-10:text='Time\: %{pts\:hms}'" outputTemps.mp4
```

or try:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -cmp 22 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=DroidSansMono.ttf: timecode='09\:57\:00\:00': r=23.976: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" -y output.mov
```

I've found this tutorial to show : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noKvwcnT9aw

Comment: ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -cmp 22 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=DroidSansMono.ttf: timecode='09\:57\:00\:00': r=23.976: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" -y output.mov

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with the question.